# Подключение google recaptcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

Есть форма на странице index.php 
В форме данные для ввода (логин и пароль) и recaptcha

```html
<form action="req.php" method="post">
  <p><input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Пароль"></p>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Leq86IUAAAAAP1NPJ4hmJNdUk9zEyyasw0_lYYe"></div>
  <p><input type="submit" name="enter" value="Отправить"></p>
 </form>
```

А работает все так 
Если рекапча не заполнена или заполнена не верна то на странице req.php выводится ошибка
А если капча пройдена верно то на странице req.php выводится логин и пароль

А мне нужно чтобы ошибки о не правильном заполнении капчи выводились на той же странице где и сама форма

reg.php
if ( $_POST['enter'] ) {

```
if ( !$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] )
    exit('Заполните капчу');

$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$key = '6Leq86IUAAAAAJHXh7awOmtDbLlejXQCxTFOyxKI';
$query = $url.'?secret='.$key.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'].'&remoteip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($query));

if ( $data->success == false){
    exit('Капча введена неверно');
} else {

exit("Логин: $_POST[login]");
```

}
}

Я пока что новичок в php.Прошу строго не судить

Comment: Если убрать экшн у формы то будет стучатся на туже страницу с которой идёт отправка. Если у вас успешная авторизация то отправляйте пользователя на странице через header('Loaction: /req.php');

Comment: @Walfter  Мне нужно чтобы данные с полей логин и пароль передавались через post запрос на страницу reg.php. А если делать просто редирект пользователя то данные не отправляются

Comment: Ответ дал как можно реализовать подобное

Answer (score 0):

Пусть форма авторизации это login.php имеет следующий вид:

```
<?
if ( $_POST['enter'] ) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['auth'] = false;
    if ( !$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] )
        exit('Заполните капчу');
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $key = '6Leq86IUAAAAAJHXh7awOmtDbLlejXQCxTFOyxKI';
    $query = $url.'?secret='.$key.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'].'&remoteip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($query));
    if ( $data->success == false){
        exit('Капча введена неверно');
    } else {
        $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
        $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST[login];
        header("Location: /req.php");
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Пароль"></p>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Leq86IUAAAAAP1NPJ4hmJNdUk9zEyyasw0_lYYe"></div>
    <p><input type="submit" name="enter" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

Соответственно и в файле req.php поменять вывод:

```
<?
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['auth'])
    exit("Login is {$_SESSION['login']}");
```

Как то так

update:
Перепутал location написал вместо header;

P.S.: session_start должна быть до вывода, так же как и header

Comment: Login is выводится пустым

Comment: Да как вы и советовали

Comment: Спасибо все получилось

Comment: еще один вопрос, как чтобы при перезагрузке страницы не пропадали введеные данные в полях логин?

Comment: @user322352 у вас сессия, берите из неё, просто так же обращайтесь как и в файле req.php